# Does devotion means chanting God name as portrayed in movies?

Tags: bhakti

Unknowingly most of us under impression that devotion means to sit in a lonely place, close eyes and repeat god name continuously so that one day god will appear in front of that devotee and offers boons.

This is all we learnt by watching our movies. It may not be correct because the intention of the director of the movie might be different. Not only that but because of the movies, we limited the god to a body.

My question is what is bhakti process one should be following to get the devine attention towards us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 9 types of devotion as mentioned in ancient scriptures

> śravaṇaṁ kīrtanaṁ viṣṇoḥ smaraṇaṁ pāda-sevanam
> arcanaṁ vandanaṁ dāsyaṁ sakhyam ātma-nivedanam
> iti puṁsārpitā viṣṇau bhaktiś cen nava-lakṣaṇā
> kriyeta bhagavaty addhā tan manye ‘dhītam uttamam

Shravan (Parikshit), Kirtan (Sukdev), Smaran (Prahlad), Padsevana (Lakshmi), Archan (Prithuraja), Vanda (Akrura), Dasya (Hanuman), Sakhya (Arjuna) and Atmanivedan (Bali Raja) - these are called Navadha Bhakti. Are.

Hearing : Continuously listening to God's play, story, importance, power, source etc. with utmost devotion with an unsatisfied mind.

Kirtan : To chant God's qualities, character, name, might etc. with joy and enthusiasm.

Remembrance : Constantly remembering God with a special feeling, remembering His greatness and power and being fascinated by Him.

Pada Sevana : Taking shelter at the feet of God and considering them as your everything.

Archana : Worshiping the feet of God with sacred material through mind, speech and action.

Salutation : To salute or serve the idol of God or the devotees present in the form of God, Acharya, Brahmin, Guru, parents etc. with utmost respect and reverence .

Dasya : To serve God with utmost devotion considering God as master and oneself as slave.

Sakhya : Considering God as your best friend, surrender everything to Him and pray for your sins and virtues with true feelings.

Atmanivedan : Surrender yourself forever at the feet of God and do not keep anything of your independent power. This is considered to be the best state of devotion.

This is mentioned in the Srimad Bhagavatha Purana.